# How to check array element is identical in mongodb query?

Tags: mongodb, nosql, mongotemplate

I have the following collection:

```
[
  {
    "_id": 1,
    "favorite": {
      "color": "red",
      "foods": {
        "fruits": "banana",
        "fastfood": [
          "burger",
          "sandwich"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "_id": 2,
    "favorite": {
      "color": "green",
      "foods": {
        "noodles": "ramen",
        "fastfood": [
          "fries",
          "burger",
          "corn dog"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "_id": 3,
    "favorite": {
      "color": "red",
      "foods": {
        "soup": "cream soup"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

And I have to following query:

```
db.collection.find({
  "favorite.foods.fruits": "banana",
  "favorite.foods.fastfood": {
    "$all": [
      "burger"
    ]
  }
})
```

Current Result:

```
[
  {
    "_id": 1,
    "favorite": {
      "color": "red",
      "foods": {
        "fastfood": [
          "burger",
          "sandwich"
        ],
        "fruits": "banana"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

**Expected Result:**
But this is not my expected result. I need to match full **favorite.foods.fastfood** object for fastfood array. If the fastfood is **NOT Identical** to my query the query should return null/false/empty.

Additionally query result with mongoTemplate is also fine for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `$setEquals` to perform the array comparison.

```js
db.collection.find({
  $expr: {
    $let: {
      vars: {
        fruits_input: "banana",
        fastfood_input: [
          "burger"
        ]
      },
      in: {
        $and: [
          {
            $eq: [
              "$$fruits_input",
              "$favorite.foods.fruits"
            ]
          },
          {
            "$setEquals": [
              "$$fastfood_input",
              "$favorite.foods.fastfood"
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
})
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/6NzjSd5pO-P)

Comment: Agreed that this is the approach of order in the array does not matter

Comment: Yes, this is my desired result. But, could you please convert this to mongoTemplate? As I am working in Spring Boot with mongoTemplate.

Comment: @AbhijitMondalAbhi Sorry but mongoTemplate is out of my wit... The best I can help is providing [this more straightforward query](https://mongoplayground.net/p/0jq6V_KoI4o) that might be easier to convert.

Comment: straight forward query is really qwesome @ray

Comment: A little bit shorter, again assuming the semantics match your desired logic (should be the same as the one above depending on the schema of the documents): https://mongoplayground.net/p/qbpS3aDAsP5

Answer (score 0):

If order matters for the purposes of being identical, then simply remove the `$all` operator:

```
db.collection.find({
  "favorite.foods.fruits": "banana",
  "favorite.foods.fastfood": [
    "burger"
  ]
})
```

[Playground demonstration](https://mongoplayground.net/p/IjinzDdLjYz)

Comment: Identical means in my case: as you are just giving burger but in the collection it is burger, sandwich. So in this scenario this is not identical and the query should return empty.

Comment: That's what the one in this answer does.  I added an extra document to your three sample documents in the playground demonstration. Please take a look to see if it meets your criteria

Comment: I do not understand why you added a new document in the collection.

Comment: To demonstrate that it does return results of the document has an array that matches exactly? Like it's trivial to write a query that doesn't return any results at all, but I presume that you are looking to return documents when they do match some conditions. The presence of that extra sample document does not change the semantics or logic of the query